# Save Map<String, List<String>> into Room android

Tags: java, kotlin, android-room

I have map:

```
 @TypeConverters(StringListMapConverter::class)
    var variantColors: Map<String, List<String>>? =  null
```

and converter:

```
class StringListMapConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(value: String): Map<String, List<String>> {
        val mapType = object : TypeToken<Map<String, List<String>>>() {

        }.type
        return Gson().fromJson(value, mapType)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromStringMap(map: Map<String, List<String>>): String {
        val gson = Gson()
        return gson.toJson(map)
    }
}
```

and I get error:

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ? extends java.util.List<java.lang.String>> variantColors;
                                                                                        ^
```

how can I resolve my problem? Where I should add this type converter for List?

Comment: have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

Define this annotation `@TypeConverters(StringListMapConverter::class)` where you are instantiating your `Room Database` e.g:

```
@Database(...)
@TypeConverters(StringListMapConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    ...
}
```